# How do I scale the size of the elements in my HTML according to screen size?

Tags: html, css, text, scaling, element

I want to scale the size of the elements within my header as the screen scales down or up in size. How can this be done? Here is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>myWebpage</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pencil.ico" />

        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>

      <body>
          <header>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
            <p>Welcome<br>Make Yourself at Home</p>
          </header>
     </body>
   </html>
```

and here is my css:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body,html {
  height: 100%;
  background: honeydew;
}

/* Header*/
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/webassets/apple.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  text-align: center;


}
h1 {
  color: honeydew;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";

}
p {
  color: honeydew;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue-Thin", sans-serif;
}
```

Here is my fullscreen page:
[image]

& here it is scaled down to the smallest window:
[image][image]

As you can see, i need the text to scale as my background did.. how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vw` for `font-size`.

```
h1{
 font-size : 7.5vw;
}

p{
 font-size : 2vw;
}
```

Demo [is here.](http://jsbin.com/duvunu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: so can i apply this to button elements?

Comment: @MikeStrong Sorry for late reply. Yes, you can apply this to any element you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 Media Queries for you purpose :-

```
.text {
font-size:15px;
}

@media (max-width:730px){
font-size:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To scale text, you don't have to use fixed `px` sizes. You are better of using relative sizes, which vary in relation to the viewport or screen size. There are several options like `em`, `rem`, `vw`.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xo41e5cx/1/) you can see how, by changing the `px` to `vw`, the text becomes responsive in relation to the viewport.

Comment: can i apply this to button elements?

Comment: @MikeStrong Yes, this is applyable to al elements that have a height.

Answer (score 2):

One of the more common ways of doing this would be a media screen.

Example:

```
@media (max-width:400px){
  h1{
    font-size: 10em;
  }
}
```

Another possible way would be to use an existing mobile responsive framework such as bootstrap. To incorporate bootstrap into your page, add this stylesheet link to the top of your page:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Read more about the bootstrap documentation here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

You should use media queries, grid layout and image class sized to 100% on your css.  I recommend you to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), a free library widely used to crete fully responsive experiences with no much hassle.

Comment: Adding a whole new library to your code for just simple text-scaling doesn't seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I did downpoint your post as I agreed with Arjun's first comment and you didn't give an answer to the question but gave some general direction. Also because your recommendation made no sense with regard to the question.